# How to Protect JSON Data

Tags: json

Hi I am using JSON on User Interface side. I want to protect that data. What are the possible ways I can protect my JSON. I have a scenario where I am having JSON Object with data on User Interface side. While performing update operation using jquery postback I am updating the JSON data and sending it back to the server. My concern here is how can I save JSON object from users to append any new object in the existing JSON object. I hope i am clear about my requirement .

Comment: Protect it from who? The user? People sniffing the network? Protect it against what type of attacks? How, specifically, is the JSON being used in the application?

Comment: If you're talking about Javascript attacks, the answer to your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3146798/328397  I'd post as an answer but this question is on hold

Comment: Can you please explain more on this or is their any sample or blog that explains this briefly please share.

Answer (score 1):

After some clarification in the comment I guess I can see where we're heading. You need data integrity protection. Digitally sign the json data using a hash algorithm (md5, sha-1, etc) and put the sign inside the json file. Next you need some sort of mechanism identyfing whether the data was forged or not.

Comment: This isn't a particularly helpful answer IMO as just saying 'go encrypt it' is like giving a child a gun and telling them to protect themselves. It probably won't end well. If you could elaborate on what sorts of encryption protocols would work especially in the context of a browser (he says in the UI so assuming browser) that would help.

Comment: He's not really saying much. So without the wider context it's no use to go into details.

Comment: So why give an answer at all then?

Comment: I have a scenario where I am having JSON Object with data on User Interface side. While performing update operation using jquery postback I am updating the JSON data  and sending it back to the server. My concern here is how can I save JSON object from users to append any new object in the existing JSON object. I hope i am clear about my requirement .

Comment: Ok but if i digitally signed the data and if i will put the sign in the json object it is exposed to the outer world any one can come and play with it , and what type of mechanism i can use for checking the data integrity whether it has been altered or not, please share any sample or blog that explains this properly.

Comment: I guess you should read more about asymmetric cryptography first.